# Bitcoin trading in Cyprus

Tags: trading

Hey guys is there any way to find out how much trading in bitcoin goes on within an individual country? I'm specifically looking for info on the country of Cyprus.

Comment: Checkout fiat leak.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link from where you can get some ideas about Cyprus trade of Bitcoins. https://localbitcoins.com/country/CY